date::make_zoned crash on Windows
I am writing a C++ cross-platform application for Windows 11 and CentOS7 (whose latest GCC version is 11).
My application has to use date.h of Mr. Howard Hinnant (and not std::chrono) for parsing timezone strings.
add_executable(myapp myapp.cpp)
set_target_properties(myapp PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE date::date date::date-tz)

std::string time_with_tz = "2024-09-30 14:53:27.123456 UTC";

std::stringstream ss(time_with_tz);
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp_with_tz;
date::from_stream(ss, "%F %T %Z", tp_with_tz); // date::parse does not work for me in both Win & Linux

date::format("%F %T %Z", date::make_zoned(date::current_zone(), tp_with_tz))

I have manually downloaded the latest tzdb-2024b.tar.lz from http://www.iana.org/time-zones and windowsZones.xml into C:\users\01258\downloads\tzdata.
My code in Linux works successfully but the same code crashes in Windows when calling date::make_zoned. What could be missing in my application? I even tried installing it using .\vcpkg.exe install date[remote-api]:x64-windows and it did not work either, still crashing in Windows.

In what way does it crash, have you tried using a debugger?

Use Howard Hinnant's "tz.h". Microsoft implementation of date time has known bugs for none English system settings.

@Red.Wave they are using Howard's version

@AlanBirtles the header includes are not reflected in code sample. I suspect that - contrary to the claim - the standard headers are use.(It's ridiculous that because of MSVC bugs, I recommend against using standard).

@Red.Wave the standard library doesn't have a date namespace though

@AlanBirtles Missed that one!

Not positive, but I strongly suspect this is a duplicate of this issue.
In a nutshell, tzdb-2024b introduced the string "April" when it intended "Apr" in one place.  This is allowed according to the IANA spec, but broke several parsers, including mine, nonetheless.
Two things have been done to fix this:

The IANA database has been patched to revert back to "Apr", but has not yet been released.
Howard's library has been patched on tip-of-master to accept "April", but a new version has not yet been released.


You could upgrade the date lib to tip-of-master, or
You could manually download tzdb-2024a.tar.lz, or
Edit your IANA tzdata/northamercia file: change "April" to "Apr" on one (non comment) line (line 2634).


Does this happen in Windows only? or could it happen in Linux too? Maybe my downloaded date library in CentOS is using an older tzdata because my app does not crash in this OS?

This is across all platforms.  However it only impacts the configuration that reads the text version of the database:-DUSE_OS_TZDB=0, which is the default configuration. And for this switch, it is the only available option on Windows.

looks like vcpkg defaults to -DUSE_OS_TZDB=1
